# How can I determine a new Reply/Forward message's parent MailItem in an Outlook 2010 C#.NET Add-in

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, mailitem

I am trying to develop an Add-in for Outlook 2010 that allows me to tag an email using an [Outlook.MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem.aspx)'s UserProperties collection. The fields are loaded from a database configuration and displayed in a task pane for population by the user when composing the email. When someone with the Add-in receives the email they can open it up and view/edit the tagged values in the same task pane.

I also want to populate a reply or forward message spawned from the tagged email with the current values. Unfortunately, I have found no way to determine what Outlook.MailItem the new email originated from. I tried using the newly created email passed to [Reply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.reply.aspx) event to find the parent, using the Parent property or GetConversation() method, both of which return null for the newly created item.

So, to summarize: is there a way to determine the spawning MailItem from which a new Reply or Forward MailItem is generated? If you need any clarification on this issue, let me know.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently developing an add-in for Outlook 2007/2010 which makes use of one user-property. I've made the experience that a MailItem with the user property set inherits it when it is forwarded. Have you already looked for the user property/properties in the new e-mail? You can use [Outlook Spy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) from Dmitry Streblechenko to explore them better.

Comment: How exactly did you make the new email inherit the user properties of its parent? Whenever I forward/reply the user properties are blank on the new email. I can't see a way of doing it without some kind of conversation search order by a timestamp.

Comment: Are you saving your mail item before forwarding?